# dynamic add items to border viewport

Tags: extjs, javascript, extjs4, viewport

I want to create a empty viewport(layout:border) first, then add items to it, finally render and show.
but when I created the viewport element, it throw an error, says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'flex' of undefined

here are my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-4.0.2a/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
Ext.require(['*']);
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'border'
    });

    var north = blablabla...
    viewport.add([north,south]);

    viewport.doLayout();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to notes that are taken from [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.layout.container.Border):

> The regions of a BorderLayout are fixed at render time and thereafter, its child Components **may not be removed or added**.To add/remove Components within a BorderLayout, have them wrapped by an additional Container which is directly managed by the BorderLayout.

And by the way

> Any Container using the Border layout **must** have a child item with region:'center'